# Why isn't npm i working after adding ssh key?

Tags: node.js, git, react-native, npm

While executing npm i command in react-native project appears the error

> Ilya Shevtsov@DESKTOP-86UQNMD MINGW64 /c/androidprojects/ProjectApp/StudyDesk (master)
> $ npm i
> npm ERR! code 129
> npm ERR! command failed
> npm ERR! command git clone ssh://git@github.com/recidive/waterline-prana.git C:\Users\Ilya Shevtsov\AppData\Local\npm-cache_cacache\tmp\git-clone-62a0c3f4 --recurse-submodules --depth=1 --config core.longpaths=true
> npm ERR! fatal: Too many arguments.
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! usage: git clone [] [--]  []
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR!     -v, --verbose         be more verbose
> ...
> npm ERR!     --sparse              initialize sparse-checkout file to include only files at root
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR!     C:\Users\Ilya Shevtsov\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2021-03-06T00_27_44_598Z-debug.log

Fragment of log:

> 5124 timing idealTree:fixDepFlags Completed in 84ms
> 5125 timing idealTree Completed in 62182ms
> 5126 timing command:install Completed in 62198ms
> 5127 verbose stack Error: command failed
> 5127 verbose stack     at ChildProcess. (C:\Users\Ilya Shevtsov\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules@npmcli\promise-spawn\index.js:64:27)
> 5127 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
> 5127 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1048:16)
> 5127 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5)
> 5128 verbose cwd c:\androidprojects\ProjectApp\StudyDesk
> 5129 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.18363
> 5130 verbose argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Users\Ilya Shevtsov\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "i"
> 5131 verbose node v14.16.0
> 5132 verbose npm  v7.6.0
> 5133 error code 129
> 5134 error command failed
> 5135 error command git clone ssh://git@github.com/recidive/waterline-prana.git C:\Users\Ilya Shevtsov\AppData\Local\npm-cache_cacache\tmp\git-clone-62a0c3f4 --recurse-submodules --depth=1 --config core.longpaths=true
> 5136 error fatal: Too many arguments.
> 5136 error
> 5136 error usage: git clone [] [--]  []

The folder C:\Users\Ilya Shevtsov\AppData\Local\npm-cache_cacache\tmp is empty

This problem appeared after generating, adding and then entering new ssh key. Reinstalling nodejs and git is not working.